# Why doesn't this work? Swift Tutorial

Tags: swift

Doing the exercise on structs, and I am confused why deck does not return an array of Cards?
I'm fairly new to C-ish languages, but experienced with object oriented languages in general.

```
struct Card {
    var rank: Rank
    var suit: Suit
    func simpleDescription() -> String {
        return "The \(rank.simpleDescription()) of \(suit.simpleDescription())"
        }
    func buildDeck() -> Card[] {
        var range = 0..52
        var deck: Card[] = []
        var suits: Suit[] = [.Hearts, .Spades, .Diamonds, .Clubs]
        for i in range {
            for suit in suits {
                var card = Card(rank: Rank.fromRaw(i)!, suit: suit)
                deck.append(card)
            }
        }
        return deck
    }
}
let threeOfSpades = Card(rank: .Three, suit: .Spades)
let threeOfSpadesDescription = threeOfSpades.simpleDescription()

var deck = threeOfSpades.buildDeck()
deck
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this isn't working for you, but I think you probably want your range to be `0..13` (or `1...13` or whatever you've set up in your `Rank`s). This is going to build a deck with 208 cards, 156 of which will be meaningless in most modern card games...

Comment: It throws an exception, right? Consider the result of Rank.fromRaw(21).

Comment: If one of you would like to post an answer, I will vote for it.  The range was the issue `1..13` instead of `0..52`, which was a remnant of the way I first tried to do it.  Thanks guys!

Comment: Interestingly enough though, it didn't throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons I suspect is on the half closed range syntax that you are using:

```
var range = 0..52
```

should be

```
var range = 0..<52
```

because after Xcode got updated. This is changed, but Apple didn't change it in its Swift book either.